# Commit with --no-verify flag as default in VSCode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I want to have, as a default configuration, the commit in VSCode using `--no-verify` flag. I have already updated the VSCode `settings.json`, in order to include `git.allowNoVerifyCommit`.

Great, now I can do a commit by presing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>, and selecting the option `Commit (No verify)`.

[image: Commit (No Verify) option]

However, I want that behaviour as default - that means, that when I press `Commit & Push` from the VSCode left menu, I want the commit to have the `--no-verify` flag. How can I acheive it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you test it? [This issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/105881#issuecomment-703080561) says it seems to work.

Comment: @VonC exactly, that works, but what I want is not just doing one commit with `--no-verify`. What I want is that to be the **default** behaviour.

Comment: I meant, it seems to be working when doing "commit & push"

Comment: @VonC No, not in my case: it does not use the flag in that case

Comment: Do you also have `git.confirmNoVerifyCommit` set to true or false?

Comment: @VonC Yes! And it still does not work 